# Is there optimized code for comparing product version in sql procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have product version as below:

How to get highest version between sql server version and Visual studio version columns in SQL procedure with optimized code

1. SQL server version: 4.5.1 , Visual studio Version: 4.51, Greater version: 4.51
2. SQL server version: 1.51.1 , Visual studio Version: 1.5.27, Greater version: 1.51.1
3. SQL server version: 1.3.5.1 , Visual studio Version: 1.3, Greater version: 1.3.5.1
4. SQL server version: 1 , Visual studio Version: 1.1.2, Greater version: 1.1.2

Comment: visual studio version, why do you want to get in sql server ?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the version numbers?   Or are you asking how to determine the greater of any two version numbers?

Comment: I am asking for how to determine the greater of any two version numbers. I am having values in DB. SO I am asking the feasibility in SQL procedure

Comment: Is the Visual Studio version stored in a database table and is something inputted manually? You want to inside a stored procedure, get the SQL server version and compare it to the Visual Studio version? Are you able to provide a table schema for the table where the Visual Studio version is stored?